# I need examples of WPF controls without XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a good book on WPF but I want some code examples of programming the system without using a alot of XAML markup.  In particular I want a rundown of individual text controls and events.

So I want a website or a book, not a snotty comment :P

Please note: stay on the topic! I am not criticizing the system. Thanks.

Comment: Glen, there may be a real question in there but you haven't asked it yet. Be more specific, add some examples.

Comment: *In particular I want a rundown of individual controls and events* - Ummm... so you want [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336706)?

Comment: Is that an answer? maybe idk, ill look, I'm new to .net

Comment: MSDN has some examples of creating WPF controls from code (it's really not different from any other control - instantiate, set properties, bindings etc...)  With that said, I try to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: Xaml is a markup language its like Html.  I hear your pain, as its a big leap.  But what your asking is like asking I want to do webdesign without any html, or I want to go scuba diving without breathing apperatus.  Perhaps you should look at silverlight instead of WP7, there are lots of interesting WP7 tutorials and lots of examples, it would be a good starting point.  As for XAML, imagine it as if it was html rather than traditional form layout system and it less scary.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to know what the XAML does? Can you include an example of XAML that you want explained?

Comment: No WPF Controls use XAML markup unless you get into their templates. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: http://www.tbiro.com/Hello-WPF-Without-XAML.htm, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15154/WPF-Windows-Code-based-layout-versus-XAML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glen, unfortunately for you WPF is not built to be used through code. Though you may do some things through code, it's much harder to do so. WPF is built as data based, so to manipulate UI you need to manipulate data, not controls. It's a complicated subject, but lets say that controls may or may not exist in runtime based on their current visibility on screen and other properties.

If you still want to experiment with this you can check out controls in [System.Windows.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.aspx) namespace. Once you need to create ControlTemplate or DataTemplate you can use [FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx).

For example of how complicated this can be you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517170/create-a-grid-in-wpf-as-template-programmatically) question. For that reason, MS suggests that even when you need to manipulate WPF through code, you should place XAML in a string and load it using [XamlReader.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590393.aspx) method (this suggestion is in Remarks section of [FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx) documentation).

Comment: I did that once, with XamlReader.Load(). It worked like a charm, but I still felt kinda' dirty.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really sure what you're asking for because XAML is simply a markup language.

If you take something like

```
<Button Name="MyButton" Content="Test" />
```

you're really saying

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Name = "MyButton";
b.Content = "Test";
```

I don't think there is any need to create a tutorial on how to make WPF controls through code-behind because the markup language does almost the exact same thing, and in most cases its really easy to convert what you see in the Markup language to code-behind.

And if you really want examples of how to create a specific control through code-behind, you can usually find plenty of code examples via Google.

Answer (score 4):

This is one Where I started With [WPFTutorials](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to learn WPF "code-first", there's really just one primary resource out there that I'm aware of:

[Sells' & Griffiths' Programming WPF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510373)

They approach WPF from a code-first perspective. I don't think xaml is even introduced until the second half of the (rather large) book.

Note that you'll also be learning to do some things the "old" way, where the newer versions of WPF have learned lessons from Silverlight, etc. (E.g., Triggers vs VisualStateManager)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx

as Ed S. suggested, this is the MSDN entry about WPF. On the left, there's a link to controls. Each one control has a link about what they do, what they are for, etc.

I found this WPF/Winform comparison helpful as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know something more about `WPF`, then you can have a look at this [blog](http://drwpf.com/blog/). You will find a lot of useful informtion about `WPF`.

Regards

Debasis